# Unable to set custom headers on AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, cors, http-headers, aws-amplify

I'm trying to set these headers for my app on Amplify but without success:

```
customHeaders:
  - pattern: /*
    headers:
      - key: Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy
        value: same-origin
      - key: Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy
        value: require-corp
      - key: Access-Control-Allow-Origin
        value: '*'
      - key: Access-Control-Allow-Methods
        value: GET
```

I've tried setting it from "App settings" >> "Custom headers" (customHttp.yml) and from the build script (amplify.yml) but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, apparently I solved editing the pattern like this (only on "customHttp.yml"), I removed the custom headers from the "amplify.yml":

```
    customHeaders:
      - pattern: '**'
        headers:
          - key: Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy
            value: same-origin
          - key: Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy
            value: require-corp
          - key: Access-Control-Allow-Origin
            value: '*'
          - key: Access-Control-Allow-Methods
            value: GET
```